# MFC create application just show in task bar like the date widget

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I want to create an application using MFC that mainly runs in background, and show the system cpu usage on the taskbar just like the system date in the taskbar shown in the below.
Key feature is:

1. an icon in the taskbar;
2. change the words or info intervally.
   How to implement this?

[image]

Comment: Do *you* want to create this application, or do you rather want *us* to do it for you?

Answer (score 1):

There are public APIs you can use to display yourself in the taskbar:

- [`Shell_NotifyIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyiconw) to create a "[tray](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030910-00/?p=42583)" icon. You can update the icon as often as you want. This is what Task manager does.
- Taskbar toolbar ([`IDeskBand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb776819(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)). This lets you create a much larger surface in the taskbar. Currently not supported on Windows 11.

Comment: [`IDeskBand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ideskband) is unsupported starting with Windows 7.

Comment: Unsupported but still works.

Comment: Didn't know nor verify. Do you happen to know which Windows release pulled the plug on Yet Another Interface (YAI!?)?

Comment: @IInspectable Still works in 8 and probably in 10 (in 11 I read somewhere you have to revert to the old taskbar with a hack). It was the typical MS thing; look we added these toolbars to the thumbnails and Windows media player uses that now so we don't need our deskband anymore and neither do you.